# Websockets, socket.io, nodejs, and security

Tags: security, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a real-time analytics application and am using websockets (through the socket.io library) along with nodejs. There will be no "sensitive" data being sent through the websockets (like names, addresses, etc). It will be only used to track visits and to track the total visitors (along with the number of visitors on the top 10 most visited URLs).

Are there any security issues that I should be aware of? Am I opening myself up to:

1. DoS attacks?
2. XSS attacks?
3. Additional security holes that could be used to gain access to the webserver/webserver's LAN?
4. Anything else I didn't mention here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `1. DoS attacks?`

You are opening yourself up against DoS attacks and if they are done properly there is almost nothing you can do against this kind of attacks.

> `2. XSS attacks?`

If you don't filter you are vulnerable to XSS attacks. I believe you could protect yourself against this using something looking like [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/jade.js#L104):

```
/**
 * Escape the given string of `html`.
 *
 * @param {String} html
 * @return {String}
 * @api private
 */

function escape(html){
  return String(html)
    .replace(/&(?!\w+;)/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

> ```
> 3. Additional security holes that could be used to gain access to the
> webserver/webserver's LAN?
> ```

You should protect yourself against LAN attacks using a firewall?

> `4. Anything else I didn't mention here?`

- If you are sending sensitive information you should sent it over SSL at least. You should also come up with some sort of authentication scheme...
- Maybe you could be vulnerable to session fixation?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can I ask how exactly I would be opening myself up to DoS attacks? I know they are possible in a lot of situations, I am just concerned about additional risk presented by the use of websockets. Fortunately, I am only going to be sending tracking data back and fourth (maybe a number or some sort of dynamic counter...I haven't thought about it yet) so I don't think I'll have to filter things. Also, there will be no way for users to input data into the websocket. The websocket is only used when a user loads a page (for tracking).

Comment: When a dos attacks is executed perfectly by for example a very large botnet there is almost nothing you can do against it. Even big sites like for example(I believe they got hit) paypal, amazone can't do anything against this. I don't know for sure if there is any additional risk. If the output(sent to browsers) is not coming from users(make sure you discard all input from users) you are safe against XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks once again for your valuable feedback :)

Comment: There is a class of DoS attacks that can be exacerbated by bad design. If a relatively small amount of traffic is causing a large amount of work and you become cpu or database io bound, you are in trouble. http/tcp overload is unstoppable ... call your upstream provider ;-)